# Separating Sitecore 6.5 Delivery and CMS Database users

Tags: sql-server, permissions, sitecore, sitecore6

We've been asked to separate as much as possible the database users between our CMS server and Delivery server.  I've not found anything regarding permissions for the different Sitecore databases for this purpose anywhere, so thought I would ask here.  Here is the plan based on what I gather the purposes for the different databases:

CMS User: read/execute to Sitecore_Analytics, read/write/execute access to Sitecore_Master, Sitecore_Web, and Sitecore_Core

Delivery User: no access to Sitecore_Master, read/execute access to Sitecore_Web and Sitecore_Core, read/write/execute access to Sitecore_Analytics

Note that we do not have any user account management on the public site, only on the CMS for content management.  Does this permission scheme seem feasible?

Comment: Is the error in the logs of CM or CD? And is this when you manually publish or have you set up automated publishing?

Comment: It's on the CM server.

Comment: I went back to the scalability document and made some additions I'd missed (including adding a ScalabilitySettings.config file).  However with that file present, when I publish, I get an SQLexception Invalid column name 'Stamp'.  This column however is in my sitecoremaster and sitecoreweb databases.  Eventqueue was previously disabled and confirmed that setting this to true in conf scalabilitysettings.config is what causes that exception.

Comment: I'm wondering if I need to set this server up for multiple instances?  Currently I have two application pools and two corresponding sites in IIS, one for the CD and one for the CM.  Does this mean there are two instances?  This is our development environment.  Our production environment uses two completely separate machines, and is set to single instance and publishing works fine...

Comment: Yes, that is 2 instances. Your prod most likely has the scalability settings configured, but it should largely work even without that, just some of the event processes would be out of whack, should not affect publishing afaik.

Comment: Prod is not configured for scalability, but it does work fine as far as publishing goes...

Comment: Seems there is still something wrong with the publishing even after sucessfully implementing the eventqueue.  I no longer see any errors when I publish in the logs, it seems like it goes through, but it is still not visible on the CD, only the CM...

Comment: Check the items are in the web database (from the desktop, switch from the database icon in the bottom right corner). Try clearing the cache from `/sitecore/admin/cache.aspx`, if that works then it is a caching issue. I've had issues with this myself for various reasons before.

Comment: I can access the cache page on the CD server and display the cache values, but cannot clear cache as it throws a SqlException (The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'ClientData', database 'Sitecore_Core')...  If I do this on the CM server it works fine but doesn't change anything on the CD server, obviously...

Comment: Turned out the issue, at least the final one, was because I did not have the scalabilitysettings.config file on the CD server only the CM server.  I don't know if this is specifically specified in the documentation, if it is, I missed it.  It's now publishing correctly!

Answer (score 1):

The permissions required for the various database are listed in Microsoft SQL Server Configuration section (page 54) of the [Sitecore Installation Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/installation_guide_sc65-a4.pdf), including details about the role membership and permissions for executing stored procedures.

The content delivery server does not need any access to the master database. Remove this from the connectionstrings and then enable the "SwitchMasterToWeb.config" in the `App_Config/Includes` folder to change any references from the master to web database.

***EDIT***

Sitecore 6.5 does not have a SwitchToMaster.config file by default, have a read of the [Scaling Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/Reference/Sitecore%206/Scaling%20Guide.aspx) Section 4.6 which provides details on manually removing the references, as well as a link to the config file for download.

***END EDIT***

You may also want to have a read of the [Security Hardening Guide](https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/65/sitecore_security_hardening_guide-sc65-66-a4.pdf) to make sure you have other areas covered.

Comment: First, I only seem mention of the CMS server permissions, not delivery server permissions in that document.  Second, it mentions giving permission to Master as well as Web.  I actually removed the Master connection string from my connectionstrings.config and get an error: ([InvalidOperationException: Unknown connection string. Name: 'master'])

Comment: The permissions are the same for both CM and CD in terms of hardening, but for CD you also need to restrict/remove access to `/sitecore`. In terms of the errors you are seeing, did you enable the `SwitchMasterToWeb.config` on your CD server? If you still have errors there must still be a reference to master in the configs somewhere, trying checking in `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` (after enabling the master connstring back again)

Comment: The error is not on the CD server but the CM Server - I have separate websites for each, with two different sets of connectionstrings. There is no SwitchMasterToWeb.config on either the CM or CD servers in /app_config/includes.  Thing is, I want to have a master db, I just want it only accessible to the CM server, and the web only accessible to the CD server.  Unless I'm not understanding something, that seems like it would provide the best separation of database users and what they can access...

Comment: Yes, I understand that, you should remove master connstring from **CD only**. Just checked and you're right about 6.5 missing the "switch to master"... Will try dig one out.

Comment: Found it, updated the post with the link to the file (and the scaling guide with more details). You'll need access to Sitecore SDN to download it though unfortunately.

Comment: updated the main item here because the comment area has limited space.